# Problema na hora de inserir dado no postgresql com jpa implementado por hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Boa tarde gostaria de saber por que está acontecendo esse erro, o projeto está com todos os jars na lib e no path porem quando vou inserir está me retornando um erro.

> Abr 19, 2014 4:49:27 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {4.0.2.Final} Abr 19, 2014 4:49:27 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>   INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.6.Final} Abr 19, 2014 4:49:27 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000205: Loaded
>   properties from resource hibernate.properties:
>   {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver,
>   hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect,
>   hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.format_sql=true,
>   hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa,
>   hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE,
>   hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false,
>   hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true,
>   hibernate.connection.pool_size=5} Abr 19, 2014 4:49:28 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021:
>   Bytecode provider name : javassist Abr 19, 2014 4:49:29 PM
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) Abr 19, 2014 4:49:29 PM
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 5 Abr 19,
>   2014 4:49:29 PM
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true Abr 19, 2014 4:49:29
>   PM
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL
>   [jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres] Abr 19, 2014 4:49:29 PM
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=postgres,
>   password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto} Abr 19, 2014
>   4:49:30 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO: HHH000400: Using
>   dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect Abr 19, 2014 4:49:30
>   PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder
>   useContextualLobCreation INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB
>   creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4 Abr 19,
>   2014 4:49:30 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator
>   initiateService INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy:
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
>   Abr 19, 2014 4:49:30 PM
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  INFO:
>   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory SLF4J: Failed to load class
>   "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation
>   (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See
>   http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. Abr 19, 2014 4:49:31 PM
>   org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache  INFO: HHH000250:
>   Starting update timestamps cache at region:
>   org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache Abr 19, 2014 4:49:31 PM
>   org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
>   WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for
>   cache named [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using
>   defaults. Abr 19, 2014 4:49:31 PM
>   org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache  INFO:
>   HHH000248: Starting query cache at region:
>   org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache Abr 19, 2014 4:49:31
>   PM org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
>   WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for
>   cache named [org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache]; using
>   defaults. Abr 19, 2014 4:49:32 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute INFO: HHH000228:
>   Running hbm2ddl schema update Abr 19, 2014 4:49:32 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute INFO: HHH000102:
>   Fetching database metadata Abr 19, 2014 4:49:32 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute INFO: HHH000396:
>   Updating schema Abr 19, 2014 4:49:32 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000261: Table
>   found: public.pessoa Abr 19, 2014 4:49:32 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000037:
>   Columns: [id, idcidade_cidade, cep, id_cliente, idpessoa, nome,
>   observacoes, endereco] Abr 19, 2014 4:49:32 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000108:
>   Foreign keys: [cidade_fk] Abr 19, 2014 4:49:32 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000126:
>   Indexes: [pkidpessoa] Abr 19, 2014 4:49:32 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute INFO: HHH000232:
>   Schema update complete Hibernate: 
>       select
>           nextval ('hibernate_sequence') Hibernate: 
>       insert 
>       into
>           pessoa
>           (nome, id) 
>       values
>           (?, ?) Abr 19, 2014 4:49:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions WARN:
>   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502 Abr 19, 2014 4:49:32 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions ERROR:
>   ERROR: null value in column "endereco" violates not-null constraint
>   Detalhe: Failing row contains (10, Andrades, null, null, null, null,
>   70, null). Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
>   transaction   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:92)     at
>   testeUnitario.TesteConexaoPostgre.main(TesteConexaoPostgre.java:19)
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:80)
>     ... 1 more Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3067)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3509)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:286)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null
>   value in column "endereco" violates not-null constraint   Detalhe:
>   Failing row contains (10, Andrades, null, null, null, null, 70, null).
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:559)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
>     ... 15 more

acredito que a implementação esteja correta
em minha entidade eu coloquei o seguinte.

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name="pessoa")
public class Pessoa implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Id  
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)  
@Column(name="id")    
private Long id;
public Long getId() {  
    return this.id;  
}
private String nome;

//get and set
```

}
não consigo compreender por que não insere, no mysql está ocorrendo tudo bem mas no postgresql não está funcionando.

minha persistence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

```
<persistence-unit name="comunicaVisual" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>entys.Pessoa</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1" />

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />

        <prop
```

erty name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />

a imagem do postre
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

espero que alguém possa ajudar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seu campo endereço parece estar indo vazio, veja o que diz a mensagem de erro

```
 ERROR: null value in column "endereco" violates not-null constraint
```

certifique-se de setar o valor de todos os atributos obrigatórios, teste novamente e se não resolver poste o erro aqui e ajudaremos

Comment: opa amigo blz, não tenho campo endereço tenho apenas id e nome.

Comment: acredito que o problema possa ser em relação as configurações do persistence, pois eu não coloquei o esquema, porem não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: o erro do campo endereco está na string de erro que voce postou, ou seja, provavelmente a tabela em que voce está tentando inserir (ou a classe da entidade mapeada no JPA) estão com o campo endereço. Leia com calma e atenção a mensagem que você vai achar a parte da mensagem falando sobre o campo endereço nao poder ser nulo.

Comment: sua configuraçao do schema está usando XML ou annotations?

Comment: a configuração que fiz na aplicação está utilizando XML

Comment: minha entidade...

Comment: faça uma coisa, acesse sua base de dados usando phpmyadmin ou algo assim, e confirme se na tabela pessoa não existe um campo endereço. se quiser exportar o sql da tabela e postar aqui podemos ver isso pra voce.

Comment: public class Pessoa implements Serializable{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


 @Id  
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)  
 @Column(name="id")    
 private Long id;
 public Long getId() {  
     return this.id;  
 }
 private String nome;

 //get e set

Comment: só tirei o nome entity e os get e set para postar

Comment: Cara você estava certo eu estava preocupado com a aplicação e havia me esquecido do Bd, muito obrigado.